# Reality check on integrability of almost-complex surface.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, complex-geometry, almost-complex

Let $(M^2,J)$ be an almost-complex surface. I do not assume integrability of $J$ now. I understand that from the Newlander-Nirenberg theorem, one of the several equivalences for the integrability of $J$ is that ${\rm d} = \partial + \overline{\partial}$. But I also know that in dimension $2$ the Nijenhuis tensor always vanishes. So this means that ${\rm d} = \partial + \overline{\partial}$ holds in dimension $2$, no matter which $J$ I begin with. So I should be able to give a direct proof of this, from scratch.

Ok, here's an attempt: assume that $(Z,\overline{Z})$ is a local complex frame for $M$, with $Z$ of type $(1,0)$ and $\overline{Z}$ of type $(0,1)$. If $(\zeta,\overline{\zeta})$ is the dual coframe, we automatically have that $\zeta$ is of type $(1,0)$ and $\overline{\zeta}$ is of type $(0,1)$.

- Let $f\colon M \to \Bbb C$ be a $0$-form. Then ${\rm d}f = Z(f)\zeta + \overline{Z}(f)\overline{\zeta}$, and hence $\partial f = Z(f)\zeta$ and $\overline{\partial}f = \overline{Z}(f)\overline{\zeta}$. Thus for $0$-forms ${\rm d} = \partial + \overline{\partial}$ holds. Beautiful.
- Let $\alpha = f\zeta + g\overline{\zeta}$ be a $1$-form. We compute $${\rm d}\alpha = {\rm d}f\wedge \zeta + f\,{\rm d}\zeta + {\rm d}g\wedge \overline{\zeta} + g\,{\rm d}\overline{\zeta} = \big(-\overline{Z}(f) + Z(g) + f{\rm d}\zeta(Z,\overline{Z}) + g\,{\rm d}\overline{\zeta}(Z,\overline{Z})\big)\zeta\wedge \overline{\zeta}.$$Since ${\rm d}\alpha$ has no $(2,0)$ or $(0,2)$ component, I conclude that $\partial\alpha = \overline{\partial}\alpha = 0$. But ${\rm d}\alpha = 0$ need not be zero.

Question: what's the screw up?

Comment: I think your notation is a little confusing so I will not directly answer the question "what am I missing", instead, I will show you a more straightforward proof. Check that the Nijenhuis tensor $N_J$ can be explicitly described as:
$N_J = \pi^{0,2}\circ d$, where $\pi^{0,2}$ is the projection of the two forms on its $(0,2)$ component and $d$ is the standard exterior derivative. Then, tell me, by dimension criterium, what must be the image of $N_J$ if not $0$?

Comment: I do not want to use the Nijenhuis tensor. I want to understand exactly in *this* calculation what went wrong. I can explain everything about the notation you may need. When I say that $Z$ is of type $(1,0)$, I mean that $JZ = {\rm i}Z$, and similarly for $\overline{Z}$, $\zeta$ and $\overline{\zeta}$. The dualities $\zeta(Z)=1$, $\zeta(\overline{Z}) = 0$, $\overline{\zeta}(Z)$ and $\overline{\zeta}(\overline{Z}) = 1$ all hold.

Comment: The definitions of $\partial$ and $\overline{\partial}$ I assume are $\partial\colon \Omega^{\ell,m}(M)\to \Omega^{\ell+1,m}(M)$, $\partial = \pi^{\ell+1,m}\circ {\rm d}$, and similarly for $\overline{\partial}$.

Comment: I think that the point is that you can not conclude that $\partial \alpha = \bar\partial \alpha = 0.$ What you can certainly conclude is that $\partial(f\zeta) = \bar \partial (g\bar \zeta) = 0.$ Note that $\partial(g\bar\zeta)$  gives you a $(1,1)$-form.

Comment: by the way, sorry for telling you notation is a bit confusing, there is been a long time since I worked with such stuff, the problem was me.

Comment: Why not? It seems that ${\rm d}\alpha$ itself is a $(1,1)$-form (which I agree is weird). Another way to see it would be ${\rm d}\alpha = {\rm d}\alpha(Z,\overline{Z})\zeta\wedge \overline{\zeta}$. The fact that $\zeta\wedge \zeta = 0$ (for the simple fact that $\zeta$ is a $1$-form) seems to support the conclusion..

Comment: Yes, $d\alpha$ is a $(1,1)$-form indeed, but $\partial$ as you defined has as its domain $\Omega^{l,m}, (l,m) \in \{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ not the whole $\Omega^1_{\mathbb{C}}(M)$, right? So it seems that is not appropriate to say that $\partial \alpha = 0$ since $\alpha \in \Omega^{1}_{\mathbb{C}}(M).$ Or perhaps is too late in Brazil and I am missing something. I mean, the right conclusion is $\partial(f\zeta) = 0.$

Comment: Observe that if you extend $\partial$ to $\Omega^1_{\mathbb{C}}(M)$ the necessarily there is a non--trivial $(1,1)$ component on to this image, so you can not conclude that $\partial \alpha = 0.$

Comment: How do you assert $\partial\alpha=0$? Apply the operator to the $[0,1]$ part of $\alpha$!

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. The two answers were also great, and the mistake was clear. A priori the equality ${\rm d} = \partial+\overline{\partial}$ is actually a lot of equalities, for each pair $(\ell,m)$, which only then we "patch together". (and yes, Leonardo's last two comments are precisely the issue I missed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have shown that if $\alpha$ is a one-form, then $d\alpha$ is a $(1,1)$-form (since there aren't any $(2,0)$ or $(0,2)$ forms on a one-dimensional almost complex manifold). Now, if $\alpha$ is a $(1,0)$-form then

$$ \partial \alpha = (d \alpha)^{(2,0)} = 0, \,\,\bar{\partial} \alpha = (d \alpha)^{(1,1)} = d\alpha  $$

and in particular

$$ d\alpha = 0 + (d\alpha)^{(1,1)} = \partial \alpha + \bar{\partial} \alpha = (\partial + \bar{\partial})(\alpha). $$

Similarly, if $d\alpha$ is a $(0,1)$-form then
$$ \partial \alpha = (d \alpha)^{(1,1)} = d\alpha, \,\,\,\bar{\partial} \alpha = (d \alpha)^{(0,2)} = 0 $$
and in particular

$$ d\alpha = (d\alpha)^{(1,1)} + 0 = \partial \alpha + \bar{\partial} \alpha = (\partial + \bar{\partial})(\alpha). $$

The point is that if you assume that $\alpha = \alpha^{(1,0)} + \alpha^{(0,1)}$ is a general one-form, you can't conclude that $\partial \alpha$ or $\bar{\partial} \alpha = 0$ since
$$ \partial \alpha = \partial \left( \alpha^{(1,0)} + \alpha^{(0,1)} \right) = (d\alpha)^{(2,0)} + (d\alpha)^{(1,1)}, \\
\bar{\partial} \alpha = \bar{\partial} \left( \alpha^{(1,0)} + \alpha^{(0,1)} \right) = (d\alpha)^{(1,1)} + (d\alpha)^{(0,2)} $$
are neither the $(2,0)$ nor the $(0,2)$ components of $d\alpha$.

Answer (score 4):

You can't conclude $\partial\alpha=\bar\partial\alpha=0$.  What you can conclude is $\pi^{2,0}(\partial\alpha)=\pi^{0,2}(\partial\alpha)=0$ and $\pi^{2,0}(\bar\partial\alpha)=\pi^{0,2}(\bar\partial\alpha)=0$.  You can't say much about the $(1,1)$-part (except that this is where your $d\alpha$ has to end up).

But of course that is enough: To get $d=\partial+\bar\partial$ on $\Omega^{1,0}$, you need to show $d(f\zeta)$ to have no $(0,2)$-part, which we know from above.  Similarly, you get $d=\partial+\bar\partial$ on $\Omega^{0,1}$.